# VBA - Microsoft Words - Implement a right click custom contextual menu

Tags: vba, contextmenu, ms-word

I will like to override the **contextual menu** of **Microsoft Word 2007** to add one more Menu Item, i.e.
look up FundCode.

The concept is that we have a series of text say:

Fund Details - **{ABC_FundCode}**

When the user highlights {ABC-FundCode} and does a right click and select our FundCode menu item, it will replace it with data from a database, i.e.

Fund Details - **ABC Infrastructure Fund - (14 million Fund Size)**

Thanks

Comment: In office 2007 you might investigate if SmartTags serve your requirements

Comment: If SmartTags do not suit, you should say how far you have got and where you are stuck. A little code never hurts.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do requires you to retrieve the CommandBar of the popup menu (I believe the name is "text", and then create a commandbarbutton object and add it to that menu.

Here's link that should help out. It's in C# but most of the code should translate easily to VBA, or whatever.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/vsto/thread/081bdeec-c1b0-4e32-b689-e0624266e7f3